# literal group works in Access 2010 but not SQl Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Hi the following query works in access 2010 but not SQL Server 2012. The error I am getting says 'Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference'.    From my research it is because the query groups by a literal.
How can I achieve the same result in SQL Server

```
SELECT 
1 AS ID, Sum([Meds].TotalMeds) AS   TotalMeds, 
Sum([Meds].Presc) AS Presc 
INTO Stats_Meds
FROM 
[Meds], Rounds
WHERE 
((([Meds].Round)<[Rounds].[Round]))
GROUP BY 
1;
```

thanks

Comment: what is this group by supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you even need a group by?  Why not just use:

```
SELECT Sum(Meds.TotalMeds) AS TotalMeds, Sum(Meds.Presc) AS Presc 
INTO Stats_Meds
FROM Meds, Rounds
WHERE Meds.Round < Rounds.Round
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you need the Id to inset into the Stats table. See if this query works for you.
DISCLAIMER(for down-voters): I have not tested this query on performance or actually run the query just a suggestion that might work for OP.

SELECT ID, SUM (WithId.TotalMeds), SUM(WithId.Presc)
INTO Stats_Meds
FROM
(SELECT 1 AS ID, Meds.TotalMeds, Rounds.Presc
FROM Meds, Rounds WHERE  Meds.Round < Rounds.Round) WithId GROUP BY ID

OR you could just do -

SELECT 1, Sum(Meds.TotalMeds) AS TotalMeds, Sum(Meds.Presc) AS Presc 
INTO Stats_Meds
FROM Meds, Rounds
WHERE Meds.Round < Rounds.Round